# How to append a PDF file to an existing one with iText?

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

In an application I am trying to append multiple PDF files to a single already existing file. Using iText I found this

Using iText I found this tutorial, which, in my case doesn't seem to work.

Here are some ways I've tried to make it work.

```
String path = "path/to/destination.pdf";
PdfCopy mergedFile = new PdfCopy(pdf, new FileOutputStream(path));

PdfReader reader;
for(String toMergePath : toMergePaths){
    reader = new PdfReader(toMergePath);
    mergedFile.addDocument(reader);
    mergedFile.freeReader(reader);

    reader.close();
}

mergedFile.close();
```

When I try to add the document logcat tells me that the document is not open.

But, `pdf` (the original document) is already open by other methods, and closed only after this one. And, `mergedFile` is exactly like in the tutorial, which, I   believe, must be right.

Did anyone experience the same problem? Otherwise, do anyone know a better method to do what I want to do?

I've seen other solutions copying the bite from one page and append them to a new file but I'm affraid this will "compile" the annotations which I need.

Thank you for your help,

Cordially,

Matthieu Meunier

Comment: (1.) You are using an old version of iText. The `PdfCopy` class was abandoned in favor of the `PdfMerger` class: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/utils/PdfMerger.html (2.) If you insist on using an old version of iText, be aware that you are missing at least one line: `document.open();` (3.) it should be `pdf.close()` instead of `mergedFile.close();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code will help you.

```
public static void mergePdfs(){
     try {
          String[] files = { "D:\\1.pdf" ,"D:\\2.pdf"  ,"D:\\3.pdf" ,"D:\\4.pdf"};
          Document pDFCombineUsingJava = new Document();
          PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(pDFCombineUsingJava , new FileOutputStream("D:\\CombinedFile.pdf"));
          pDFCombineUsingJava.open();
          PdfReader ReadInputPDF;
          int number_of_pages;
          for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                  ReadInputPDF = new PdfReader(files[i]);
                  copy.addDocument(ReadInputPDF);
                  copy.freeReader(ReadInputPDF);
          }
          pDFCombineUsingJava.close();
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
}
```

Comment: Correct. In the snippet in the question, the `Document` instance isn't opened and isn't closed. I updated your example, because there is no need to loop over the pages. You can add the complete document at once with the `addDocument()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm going to try this. Just one question. In your snippet, does the `pDFCombineUsingJava` already exists in the filesystem can it be in memory before being saved on the filesystem?

Comment: Your code worked like a charm! Thank you :D If I got it I think the pdf must be registered before being appended with other pdfs :D

Comment: @MatthieuMeunier , pDFCombineUsingJava  is a new Document object , even file "CombinedFile.pdf" need not to be on file system. It will create one if not exists.

Comment: I finally figured it out, it works perfectly now, thank you all guys ^^

Comment: Is there a way to "append" only one file at a time, creating a new page sequence?